# Aircraft parts database

Tags: data-request, transportation, products

Is there an open dataset of aircraft parts?

Each part has a unique number. Several services provide search across resellers. These searches return little details on the part itself, only reseller contacts.

FAA maintains [several datasets](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?publisher=Federal%20Aviation%20Administration), one of which is aircraft vehicle registrations:

- http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/

No parts data. Though someone must certify all parts and assign numbers.

Who maintains this data or is supposed to have it?

Comment: What makes you think parts have a unique number? Usually its only unique to a manufacturer, so you need the manufacturer ident as well.  Then the manufacturer may keep it proprietary.... For US military (some NATO) stuff, FEDLOG (http://www.dla.mil/HQ/InformationOperations/Offers/Products/LogisticsApplications/FEDLOG.aspx) is the authority, but its arguable whether its open data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Parts Manufacturer Approvals

FAA actually publishes parts approvals, but Google doesn't show it in top results:

- http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgpma.nsf/MainFrame?OpenFrameSet

> This database contains the FAA Parts Manufacturer Approvals and may be viewed by make, PMA Holder, and part number.

### Aircraft Replacement Parts Guide

A commercial database that groups standard parts together:

- https://www.aircraftspruce.com/menus/st/ac.html

It helps in matching similar parts with different approval numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Also another commercial PN database (this one is really huge, I think they say that they have more than 50 millions PNs): https://partnumber.bid